# Media query incorrectly returning true?

Tags: css

Why would the following media query return true and be applied to a page that is rendered at greater than the width specified?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){}
```

I'm baffled.

Comment: Common troubleshooting.. do you have a viewport set in the `head`..?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll check!

Comment: Reproduce you problem in JSFiddle.

Comment: @Drew Set a viewport, then test it. It should work.

Comment: @TigranPetrossian seems to work appropriately in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZj8U/

Comment: @JoshC So I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` within the head tag, but it still seems to be applying the styles from the media query--any ideas?